# Why I cannot get form control from NgForm

Tags: angular

I have simple form

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" name="myname" required [(ngModel)]="comment">
    <mat-error>Is required lol</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" required name="some">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and component as

```
export class InputOverviewExample {
  comment = null;
  @ViewChild('f')
  form: NgForm


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.form.controls);
    console.log(Object.keys(this.form.controls));

    console.log(this.form.controls.myname);
    console.log(this.form.controls['myname']);
  }
}
```

The thing is, console output is:

```
{}
​
    myname: Object { pristine: true, touched: false, status: "INVALID", … }
        Array []
        undefined
```

So why I cannot access form controls by name, and why `Object.keys` returns empty array while console says there are some keys in `form.controls` ??
This is a playground so please ignore duplicated form inputs etc.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urqles

Comment: because you are using `template-driven-form` and not `reactive-form`

Comment: Reactive forms are synchronous while template-driven forms are asynchronous

Comment: And second point here is that you don't understand how browser console works

Comment: Probably not, but you could clarify that for me and all the others.

Comment: Take a look at this simple example https://jsfiddle.net/rvucjuah/ Here is my output http://take.ms/Id6WP

Comment: @yurzui now that is something I would not expect. Clarifies what is happening in my situation... What is the reasoning behind such "delayed" implementation of console ?

Comment: ahh so stringify that would simply fail. And yep I am correct. So the problem was with console behaviour ;) Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed the onInit implementation,

First add `InputOverviewExample implements OnInit` to correctly implement and use the `ngOnInit` function.

Second, Since the **Reactive forms are synchronous**, the `console.log` runs before the form gets `initialized` and before the `form control` gets added.

Also, the **general implementation** of form control uses the `form builder` in constructor, since you havent taken that, you had faced this, so the below code will solve it for you

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  comment = null;
  @ViewChild('f')
  form: NgForm


  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.form.controls);
    console.log(typeof this.form.controls);
    console.log(Object.keys(this.form.controls));

    console.log(this.form.controls.myname);
    console.log(this.form.controls['myname']);
    })

  }
}
```

[**Here is the DEMO of the working code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urqles-5chrl6?file=app/input-overview-example.ts)

**Ps:**

For your question *So template driven forms works on reactive forms API under the hood?*, the **ANSWER is yes**

Here is the explanation:

> The NgModel directive creates the FormControl instance to manage the
>   template form control and the name attribute tells the NgModel
>   directive what key to store that FormControl under in the parent
>   FormGroup

```
<input name="foo" ngModel>
```

is is equivalent to:

```
let model = new FormGroup({
  "foo": new FormControl()
});
```

**The main problem for you is the console behaviour,**

> `Console` executed first and later the value is assigned to it, so
>   will not get access to any of the methods when value gets assigned
>   after the execution of console.

[Here is a nice example given by @yurzui](https://jsfiddle.net/rvucjuah/)

Comment: yes the general implementation of form control uses the form builder in constructor, since you havent taken that, you had faced this, so the above steps will solve it for you.

Comment: So template driven forms works on reactive forms API under the hood? Didn't know that.

Comment: Can you tell me why `console.log(this.form.controls);` prints `myname` control in content - i mean without timeout, in my scenario

Comment: It is just displaying as an object, but it really didnt get that object into that place when you consoled it, so any methods of it are not available without timeout

Comment: since the value is added synchronously after it is declared, the `console.log` before the change of object doesnot get access to its properties

Comment: yurzui gave me fine exmaple of what is happening here and make me confused as console printout was simply missleading to me. Ill upvote for fine information, but actual "resolution" is pointing out that console does not print what I expected it to be printing - so console showing that keys are there is misleading. If I would know that it shows `object view` at some point in time, probably wouldn't end up with such mind**** :)

Comment: yes the console behaviour is also a problem, because `console` executed first  and later the value is assigned to it

Comment: @Antoniossss, I added all the required points now in my answer

Comment: I added the explanation for Template forms using my control, and the `console.log` behaviour

Comment: As this was just a prequel for marking all controls as touched (to trigger validation) i guess ill will have to switch to reactive forms as I dont want any timeouts here.

Comment: Just a comment: altough overall solution is fine, it is required to point out that `implements OnInit` is not required at all and ngOnInit will be still called. Implements clause here is just syntatic sugar for compiler/IDE but has no effect on runtime.

Comment: yeah, but in previous versions of Angular, `implements OnInit` was cumpolsary as it used to throw error, but they removed that in latest versions of the same.

Comment: Which versions are you talking about? This issue was raised on ver 4 and that still applied back then.