# Why is formGroup (formRef.form) empty in ngAfterViewInit?

Tags: angular, forms

I realise that my `formRef.form.controls` returns an empty array in ngAfterViewInit. I use template-driven form and there are 4 elements in the form. They are available after some time. But I need them to be in `formRef.form.controls`.

So, can I subscribe to some event which signals that the form is ready? Or use some other approach?

Here is the small StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngafterviewinit-quirks

Comment: when are you building the form?

Comment: I use the template driven form with `@ViewChild(NgForm) private formRef: NgForm;`.

Comment: I've added a small stackblitz example.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267808/why-i-cannot-get-form-control-from-ngform . Also this is fast edit of your stackblitz that has ugly workaround: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngafterviewinit-quirks-b5renn .
In short: Controls are not initialized at time of ngAfterViewInit call. Sadly.